# Jquery toggle only fires once

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the following code which is used to slidein/out a div (shopping basket) on a page. However, the code will only fire once (open once, close once). Does the toggle need to be reset in some way?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var miniBasketHeight = -$('#minibasket div.outer').height();

    $('#minibasket a.opener').toggle(
        function(e) {
            console.log("open");
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find('div.outer').animate({top: 0, opacity: 1 }, 700 );
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log(miniBasketHeight);
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find('div.outer').animate({top: miniBasketHeight, opacity: 0 }, 700 );
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML? For example what differs from here? http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/sf3cE/

Comment: Hi Nick,

The HTML was:
    <li id="minibasket"> 
     <a class="opener" href="#"> 
           <span>Your cart is empty</span> 
          </a> 
     <div class="outer"> 
      <div class="inner"> 
       <p>This is the minibasket and will show the items.</p> 
       <a href="#">Checkout</a> 
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </li> 

But I've now fixed this using:

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#minibasket a.opener').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('div.outer').slideToggle('slow', function() {
   //Animation complete
  });
 });
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been resolved using slideToggle()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#minibasket a.opener').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.outer').slideToggle('slow', function() {
            //Animation complete
        });
    });
});
```